# Make everything page representing data from different tables in different html structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a page "everything" on my website where will be all my users activity presented. So I need to make sql from two tables "images" and "user_favorites" and output all to this html design

My tables structure:

**users**

```
id
```

**images**

```
id
user_id
image
description
date
```

**user_favorites**

```
id
date
```

I have got this **sql** query

```
function users_everything($user_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT 
                i.description as text, 
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date) as image_date, 
                COALESCE ( imgcount.cnt, 0 ) as comments,
                fav.id as favorite_id,
                r.image as favorited_image,
                u2.username as favorite_user,
                t.image as favorite_user_image                                                            
            FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN images i ON i.user_id = u.id
            LEFT JOIN images p ON p.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u.id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM commentaries GROUP BY image_id  ) imgcount ON i.id = imgcount.image_id

            LEFT JOIN user_favorites fav ON fav.user_id = u.id                
            LEFT JOIN images r ON r.id = fav.image_id
            LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = r.user_id                                
            LEFT JOIN images t ON t.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u2.id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)                                                                

            WHERE i.user_id = ?
            ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

My "images" table have 1 record and "user_follow" 2 records but if I do foreach it returns two favorites and two images (image) was duplicated.

I do not make such things like everything page before where will be presented data from different pages to different html structure. I suppose you have experience with it and helps me

Comment: "Date" is a reserved word in most databases, consider changing the name of it to preserve correct SQL also in the future. Otherwise you should escape the name constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your array of flat records into a tree structure in which each image contains a list of favorites.  Something like:

```
$images = array();
foreach($everything_list as $item)
{
    // Check to see if already encountered this image
    $imageId = $item['image_id'];
    if (!isset($images[$imageId]))
    {
        // New image
        $image = array();

        // Do this for each image attribute
        $image['image_id'] = $item['image_id'];

        $image['favorites'] = array();
        $images[$imageId] = $image;
    }
    // Add Favorite
    $favorite = array();

    // Do this for each favorite attribute
    $favorite['favorite_id'] = $item['favorite_id'];

    $images[$imageId]['favorites'][] = $favorite;
}
print_r($images);
```

Comment: Thank you it is good but still have some questions. 1) for example I have [image_date] in images and [favorite_day] in favorites is it possible to make result ordered by date? I have add to SQL order but it sort inside each array. for example first go all images (sorted by date) after goes all favorites (sorted by date). Is it possible to sort them all by one date ? for example now I heva print_r 3 items and to show FAVORITE|IMAGE|FAVORITE or it is impossible ? I have spent hours looking, searching examples on web but nothing, still a lot website have such pages where out all user activities

Comment: sql gurus can do some amazing things with sorting and grouping.  But sometimes it's easier to just use php's usort http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.  usort allows you sort an array with your own user defined compare function so you can slice and dice however you want.

Comment: thank you for advice I will look but will usort will sort in my case ? As I understand it is array in array

Comment: Yep.  You will end up comparing two arrays against each other but usort can handle it.